# Question about translation between "jump" and "jump and link"

Tags: riscv

In the risc-v specification, it says that `j` is pseudocode for `jal`. I'm confused about how this works since the range of immediate values is different for `j` (25-bit immediate) and `jal` (20-bit immediate) - and also `jalr` with a 12-bit immediate.

Any clarification on how this translation is handled would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where did you see that immediate is 25bits for j pseudocode instruction ?

Comment: @FabienM Our lecture slides indicate that for the jump pseudo-op, there is the 7-bit opcode and the remaining 25 bits is for the immediate offset. So just to clarify, loading in a >20 bit offset in a jump instruction won't transform it into a lui+jalr instruction to accomodate the extra bits and 20 bits is the max immediate offset for jump?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, immediate value size is not different for `j` and `jal` as official documentation say:

> Plain unconditional jumps (assembler pseudoinstruction J) are encoded as a JAL with rd=x0.

Following instruction :

```
j offset
```

Will expand to

```
jal x0, offset
```

Maybe you thought that the 5bits that encode the `rd` register (`x0`) was included in offset, but not.